# shopify product page special price after regular price

Tags: templates, shopify, price

I am trying to swap position of regular price and special price on product page.

My manager want to show regular price with line through and special price after that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

In asset theme.js.liquid find

```
customPriceFormat = ' <span aria-hidden="true">' + customPrice + '</span>
customPriceFormat += ' <span aria-hidden="true"><s>' + comparePrice + '</s></span>';
```

and swap position like below

```
customPriceFormat = ' <span aria-hidden="true"><s>' + comparePrice + '</s></span>';
customPriceFormat += ' <span aria-hidden="true" class="sale-price">' + customPrice + '</span>';
```